# Using IN condition For many devices ? Any other better option

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve a report from one of the table based on some server names.
I got a list of almost 40k servers.

I added these devices to the temp table and in my main select query I have used the where condition like below:

```
select col1,col2,.... from main table 
join table 2 on ...
join table 3 on ..
join table 4 on ..
join table 5 on ..
join table 6 on ..
where devices in (select devices from temp table)
```

**Note: There are many tables that are joining the main table, hence multiple joins are included.(I have read only access to the database)**

But the records seems to be too huge and the tempdb is throwing error, as the temp table space has become full.
How do I fetch the data?

I know that I can fetch the data using the list of 1000 devices at one go, any other advice? Since the data is huge.

Comment: Please edit your question so 1) it has a title that actually covers your question, and 2) it includes the actual error(s) you get. Just a hint: consider **joining** to the 'temp table' instead of using a `in (select devices from temp table)`

Comment: Nitpicking: there is no "tempdb" in Oracle.

Comment: Temporary Table space I meant.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel- I am already joining many table will one more join not create the same error?

Comment: You have 3 options, `IN`, `JOIN` and `EXISTS`. `IN` is the most efficient, [details here](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/30/in-vs-join-vs-exists-oracle/)

Comment: But In has the capacity of 1000 values only ? Am I right? I am new to oracle sql developer.

Comment: @JohnHC I don't think that that article comes to that conclusion.

Comment: It could be the joins that are using temporary tablespace space, if sort-merge joins or hash joins are spilling to disk. I doubt the IN is anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would talk to the DBA and see if they can increase the TEMP tablespace size, or ask what the setting for pga_aggregate_target is, and see if that can be increased. From your end (the client end), you could switch your query to an EXISTS statement (assuming there is a decent index to join with). If that's the table causing the issues, EXISTS should switch from HASH JOIN (which I'm guessing it's doing) to a NESTED LOOPS with an INDEX, removing the need for any temp space. Your query may run slow(er) (not sure what the best explain plan for this statement is without looking at it in more depth), but at least it should complete.